# jQuery UI Autocomplete: How to make TAB select the first option on the list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using the jQuery UI autocomplete, is there any way to automatically select the first item on TAB click (or at least stimulate a down key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below jQuery for this:

```
$("#tags").on('keydown', function (e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    //if alt pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var _firstitem = $(".ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item").first().text();
                    $(this).val(_firstitem);
                }
            });
```

Please have a look on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv38yozx/):

https://jsfiddle.net/mv38yozx/

Hope it will help you.